# Let $f(x)$ determine the value of $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ determine the value of $\int_2^3 \frac{dx}{\log(x)}$ in terms of $f(x),$ my teacher tells me that the solution is between sustitution, i attemped $u = \log(x) \,du = \frac{1}{x}\,dx$, $dx = e^u\,du$, also my teacher says that the interval of integration won't be the same but it's possible to split the integral, sorry im not native english speaker lol

$$f(x) = \int_0^x e^{e^t} \, dt$$

Comment: $g(x)$ as you wrote it is a number not a function.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you might mean by "Let $f(x)$ determine the value of $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$".

Comment: i need transform this $g(x) =\int_2^3 \frac{dx}{\log(x)}$ in $f(x)$ form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: So what do you get when you substitute $u=\log x$? After that, try $t=\log u$.

Comment: Thank you very much :),i did $u = log(x)$ i get $\int_{log(2)}^{log(3)} \frac{e^u}{u} du$, then with your hint i get$\int \frac{e^{e^t}\cdot e^t}{e^t}dt$and finally $\int e^{e^t}dt$, the limits of integration are $log(log(2) ,log(log(3))$?

Comment: That looks right. Now try to express that using only values of $f()$ (which I think is what you are asked?).

Comment: i think that the limits of integration are $\int_{log(log(2))}^{log(log(3))} e^{e^t} dt$, if this is right we can express like this $f(b) - f(a)$, $\int_{0}^{log(log(3))} e^{e^t} dt - \int_{0}^{log(log(2))} e^{e^t} dt$, but i´m not sure of the intervale

Comment: Yes, you are correct.